# Select data from MySQL table based on condition

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from a table for today's date. Here is my `query`

```
$query="select verse,refer,dayorder from dailybread WHERE date='$today'";
```

If the date is not today's date,then it should retrieve information from the table where the date is something like `'01.08.2008'`.(I have given data for this date).

How could I check the condition?

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to retrieve the information from today's date if it is found or you have to display the information from other dates.

Comment: It would be useful to know how you set `$today`

Comment: What do you mean by `If the date is not today's date` you set `$date` so how could it not be todays date?

Comment: Do the check in the php code and format the parameter in the where criteria accordingly.

Comment: His question is little bit confusion and he is itself seems confusing. have to improve the Question a more clear :)

Comment: What datatype is your `date` column in the table? DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP or Gof forbid VARCHAR

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: $date = ($today == date("dd/mm/YYYY")) ? $today : '01.08.2008'; // you should use date format that can be used in SQL Query though, so I would convert these (YYYY-mm-dd) or something like that.
$query="select verse,refer,dayorder from dailybread WHERE date='$date'";

Comment: Still no Clear explanation given from @user2691462..

Answer (score 1):

Get your date in **YYYY-mm-dd** format and try following query

`$query="select verse,refer,dayorder from dailybread WHERE date(date)='$today'"`;

Answer (score -1):

Here is a suggestion: Don't enter any data for the dates when its 'holiday'. 
and after executing the query you can check if any row were returned or not.(Obviously 0 row will be returned when its 'holiday' as no data is present for that date.)

code will be something like this:

```
$query="select verse,refer,dayorder from dailybread WHERE date='$today'";
$con=mysqli_connect("ip_of_machine_with_db","db_user","db_password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowCount > 0){
     // Data is present for the given date, perform your logic here.
}else{
     // No data found. 
}
```

Comment: The Questionnaire has not given enough info about the question and why so you provide the answers over here :(

Comment: Let him first explain the question clearly and you explain after that.. :(

Comment: I need to fetch data from my database based on today's date in my page on working days.Actually I am feeding data into my table and also dates.I want to display verses for my page every day .If it is a holiday,then no body will see my page.In those days I don't want my page to display errors.For that I have inserted some date like(01.08.2008) and I am trying to display data from that date during holidays.Hope you can understand my query.

Comment: Is there any data present for 'holiday' date in your database ?

Comment: No I didn't give any data.If those days are holidays,I skip those dates.So ,in those cases, I do not my page to display any errors .So that I have given data by mentioning this date(01.08.2008) and trying to fetch this data during holidays.